# Error displaying google maps in firefox

Tags: google-maps

I have a problem displaying the google map in firefox.

[image: picture]

How can i display the map in Firefox?
And how can i setup the map to show the longitude and latitude in the middle of the map?

Here is my code:

Comment: how can i display the map in Firefox?

Comment: and how can i setup the map for display the Langitudine and latitudine in middle of the map.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give your map div a size before you display it or trigger the resize event on the map once it is displayed (`google.maps.events.trigger(map, 'resize');` where "map" is the google.maps.Map object).

Comment: <div id="map_go_full""></div>

CSS {#map_go_full{float:left;width:630px;height:420px;}}

Comment: I don't know.  You didn't provide any of your code (the snippet in the comments is not code and is not useful).  A picture can show the problem, which is fairly common, but can't provide any more than a general solution.  If you can't (or won't) provide your code, searching this website and/or the v3 group (https://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-js-api-v3) for top left (and possibly tabs) should yield lots of results.

Answer (score 0):

this is how you display your map:

**HTML**

```
<div id="map_go"></div>
```

**JS**

```
<script>
directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();

var PortoAlegre = new google.maps.LatLng(-30.034176, -51.229212);
var myOptions = {
    zoom: 14,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    center: PortoAlegre
}

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_go"), myOptions);
directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
</script>
```

**CSS**

```
#map_go {border: 1px solid red; width: 95%; height: 350px;}
```

see it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/RASG/PfggR/

Like [geocodezip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12808406/982924) said, you must set the size of your `div` (width and height)

Comment: Yes and if i use 2 maps on the same page?

Comment: i dont think so, i use in tabs... please look at http://s1.xfactor-online.com/ - how can i display google line between points in route planner?